# Plotting an extremly large output

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I'm trying to plot the solutions of this determinant:

```
Ms = 24;
Mc = 12;
{a1, a2} = { 2.864*10^(-10), 3.879*10^-(10)};
 A = ({
       {Ms*ω^2 + 4 α,
        -α*(1 + E^(-I*a1*x)),
        -α*(E^(-I*(a1*x + a2*y)) + E^(-I*y*a2))},
       {-α*(1 + E^(I*x*a1)), 
        Mc*ω^2 + β + 2*α,
        -β},
       {-α*(E^(I*(a1*x + a2*y)) + E^(I*y*a2)),
        -β, 
        Mc*ω^2 + β + 2*α}
      })
det = FullSimplify[Det[A]]
Solve[det==0,ω]
```

Mathematica's output is extremely large and complicated and I have not managed to plot any solution. I'm pretty sure that at least three of the solutions should be Reals (if not, my equations are incorrect).

`Mc` is the the carbon atom's mass (12), and `Ms` the silicon mass (24).

`a1` and `a2` are lattice parameters ( 2.864*10^(-10)m and 3.879*10^-(10)m, respectively).

`β` and `α` are unknowns.

So, for what values of `β` and `α` the are three real solutions?

**Update**

Thanks to bbgodfrey, I realize that all the solutions are actually imaginary, nevertheless with physical sense. I've plotted them with adimensional numbers 2.864 and 3.879 and I obtained two optical branches and one acoustic branch but imaginaries: This means that the structure is not stable under this configuration or that we need additional considerations to carry out the calculus. 
[image: phonons 3d]

Comment: As far as I can see, all the solutions have significant imaginary parts for `{\[Beta] -> 10, \[Alpha] -> 12}`

Comment: Thanks. For wich values of `\[Beta]` and `\[Alpha]` there are real solutions?

Comment: That question changes the focus a lot. Please edit your question above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ans = Solve[det == 0, ω]
```

produces six answers that are, apart from roundoff, pure imaginary.  A plot of the imaginary part of one of them can be obtained from

```
Plot3D[Im[ω /. Part[ans, 2] /. {x -> x1, y -> y1}], {x1, -2, 2}, {y1, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

**Update**

The plot above is just noise, compounded by branch cuts.  Why this is so can be seen by evaluating `det` at some random point.

```
Simplify[SetPrecision[det /. {x -> .2, y -> .2}, 40]]
```

Which yields

```
(8.031847270637477260369182`2.928576922927133*^-33 + 
 5.95570041038179925907414258290373255`13.13160160204105*^-23*I) + 
 (50688.0000000000000009218737870848002370048683553533396658284684`37.71094414544172 - 
   4.367513634279986123321037894129403867`12.700725535263826*^-22*I)*ω^2 + 
 (26496.0000000000000004818885705216001238889084584801548253195142`37.71198463530822 - 
   2.283018490646356382645087990113097476`12.705632869758798*^-22*I)*ω^4 + 
 (3456.0000000000000000628550309376000161594228424104549772155649`37.70570161242444 - 
   2.97785020519089962953707129145186627`12.705632869758803*^-23*I)*ω^6
```

The term proportional to `ω^0` is, for all practical purposes, equal to `0`.  If it is dropped, then the solutions of the remaining quadratic in `ω^2` are `-4` and `-3.66667` plus a small imaginary part.  These numbers are sitting on the branch cut of `Sqrt`, so tiny variation in the imaginary part of `ω^2` lead to large changes in the imaginary part of `ω`.

A better approach is to obtain the roots of `det` symbolically and only then substitute the various constants, yielding the solutions for `ω^2` of `{0., -4., -3.66667}` accurate to `MachinePrecision`.

**Values of α and β yielding three real solutions.**

Because `a1` and `a2` are so very small, they can be set to `0` for obtaining values of α and β that yield three real solutions.  Doing so leads to a cubic polynomial in `ω^2`

```
3456 ω^6 + 192 ω^2 α (α + β) + 576 ω^4 (3 α + β)
```

which has three non-negative solutions for `ω^2` only for `α` negative and `β < -α`.

Comment: Hello! Thank you very much for your time :) With your answer I obtain 3 reals solutions, but constants... and they haven't got much sense. The problem i'm treating  is the calculus of phononic dispersion of a bidimensional material with 3 non equivalents atoms. I should obtain 1 solution that converge 0 when x,y tend to 0 (acoustic branch) and 2 that don't converge to 0 (optical branches). something like that. http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/04/Diatomic_phonons.png/220px-Diatomic_phonons.png
Anyway, thank you very much.

Comment: I would expect constants in problems like this to be expressed in dimensionless terms, not AMU and meters.  You might wish to check on this.